# What is this, when i debug xaml (Univesal) apps?

Tags: xaml, debugging, win-universal-app

Does anyone knows wat those black boxes are when you debug an xaml app?

It shows also on top of visual studio.
Can I disable this?

Thanxxx.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is FPS counter. Remove this line from App.xaml.cs to disable it.

```
this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
```